# R: use a vector to add colour to a plot

Tags: r, plot

According to [this website](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block15_colorMappingBase.html), I should be able to colour the points on a plot based on the value of the colour I have in a variable, something like this (direct quote):

```
(jDatColor <- merge(jDat, jColors))
##   continent    country year      pop lifeExp gdpPercap   color
## 1    Africa    Eritrea 2007  4906585   58.04     641.4 #1B9E77
## 2    Africa       Chad 2007 10238807   50.65    1704.1 #1B9E77
## 3  Americas    Jamaica 2007  2780132   72.57    7320.9 #D95F02
## 4  Americas       Cuba 2007 11416987   78.27    8948.1 #D95F02
## 5  Americas Costa Rica 2007  4133884   78.78    9645.1 #D95F02
## 6      Asia      Nepal 2007 28901790   63.78    1091.4 #7570B3
## 7    Europe    Germany 2007 82400996   79.41   32170.4 #E7298A
## 8    Europe     Norway 2007  4627926   80.20   49357.2 #E7298A

#And now we can provide this new color variable as the value of the col = argument.

plot(lifeExp ~ gdpPercap, jDatColor, log = 'x', xlim = jXlim, ylim = jYlim,
     col = color,
     main = 'custom color scheme based on Dark2', cex = 2)
legend(x = 'bottomright', 
       legend = as.character(jColors$continent),
       col = jColors$color, pch = par("pch"), bty = 'n', xjust = 1)
```

[image]

I want to do this with a 1-D scatterplot, called a `stripchart`. My (MWE) code looks like this:

```
total_data <- floor(runif(8000, 1,101))
class_val <- c(rep('one', 1000), rep('two', 1000), rep('three', 1000), rep('four', 1000), rep('five', 1000), rep('six', 1000), rep('seven', 1000), rep('eight', 1000))

colour_vals_pl <- rep(c('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'dark blue', 'grey', 'pink', 'cornflowerblue', 'brown'), each=1000)
colour_vals_pl <- factor(colour_vals_pl, levels=c('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'dark blue', 'grey', 'pink', 'cornflowerblue', 'brown'), ordered=TRUE)

class_val <- factor(class_val, levels=c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'), ordered=TRUE)

datatouse <- cbind.data.frame(total_data, class_val, colour_vals_pl)

stripchart(total_data~class_val, main='Power law epidemic lengths', ylab="Epidemic duration (days)", xlab="Class", pch=20, vertical=TRUE, col=colour_vals_pl, data=datatouse)
```

which produces this:

[image]

I want each line (one, two, three, etc) to be a different colour, according to the definitions I provided in `colour_vals_pl`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you use `col=1:8` it works for me. Not sure how you defined colour_vals_pl...

Comment: Change to `colour_vals_pl <- c('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'dark blue', 'grey', 'pink', 'cornflowerblue', 'brown')`. And *do not convert to factor*, and it works for me.

Comment: Yes,  @ChiPak  has it.  Do not convert the colors to a factor and it works.

Comment: Ah - so R automatically knows to replicated 'red' 1000 times, for example. Nice! Thanks @ChiPak